# Silverlight 3, how do I render linkbutton in datagrid row cell, based on conditional?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a grid, which pulls back information from a web service.
Column 3 is now going to sometimes have a value, "STP Customer", which should have a hyperlink and for other data in that column there is no hyperlink.

How can I render the hyperlink on the condition?

Pseudo code:

```
void onRenderCell( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ( sender is DataGridTemplateColumn && e.Cell.Data.Value == "STP Customer")
    {
        e.Cell.Text.Add(new Hyperlink(name="STP Customer", link="/StpCustomer.aspx?id=1");
    }
}
```

Again this is pseudo - I don't know what code :)
but hopefully it conveys what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom binding of the list to your code.
For example, take and Filed like, say, String `HyperLinkNaviagtion`.

when you get values from the service then before assigning the list to your grid, assign `HyperLinkNaviagtion` some value like,

```
if(SomeCondition)
{
   // Navigate to Google.
   HyperLinkNaviagtion ="www.google.com";
}
else
{
   // Navigate to Yahoo.
   HyperLinkNaviagtion ="www.yahoo.com";
}
```

and in XAML, do the following.

```
NavigateUri="{Binding HyperLinkNaviagtion }"
```

Do let me know if you need more.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I went with this: I placed a StackPanel in the xaml for the DataTemplate, then put a textBlock and a hyperlinkbutton in there. I set the visibility for one to 'collapsed' and the hyperlinkButton's visibility to visible. I bound these to a model, and when I need to , I can call the model.SetSpecialCustomer(true)   or something along those lines.   thanks anyway for the help.